# LeL $f: (0, \infty)\to R$ be continuous and $f(x)\leq f(nx)$ prove $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ exists

Tags: limits, continuity

Let $f: (0, \infty)\to R$ be  continuous such that  $f(x)\leq f(nx)$ for all positive $x$ and natural $n$.  I'd like to prove  $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ exists finite or infinite   but I'm not quite sure how to persou this way

Any piece of advice would be much appreciated

Comment: does it work for $\ln(x)$ ?

Comment: Are you sure the condition is not reversed $|f(nx)|\le |f(x)|$ ?

Comment: @drea Zwin, I'm sure

Comment: If you want to prove the limit exists whether finite of infinite you have to specify it explicitly in the wording of the problem. By default $\lim f(x)$ exists means that this limit should be finite too.

Comment: @zwim Yes, indeed. I have just voted to reopen that question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't necessarily. Take $f:(0,+\infty)\to \Bbb R$ as $f(x)=x.$ Then, $f(x) \leq f(nx)$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)=+\infty.$

Comment: @Dear Magnusseen, I want to prove this limit exists finite or infinite

Comment: @user62498. if the limit is infinite it is said to not exist. It exists only if it is finite.

Comment: @ Krishna. I gonna  prove the limit exists and finite

Comment: I do not understand this answer, from my point of view $\infty$ is a limit, then the limit exists. $\sin(x)$ on the contrary has no limit at $\infty$, the limit does not exist.

Comment: @nicomezi you see there is no point of view here, it is defined by mathematicians as such.

Comment: @Krishna you say when the limit is $\infty$ we have to say the limit exists?

Comment: @krishna Terminology may vary according to where you are. This is why i am asking the question. According to the french Wikipedia, if $f(x) \to \infty$ at some point then the limit exists (and is $\infty$).

Comment: @user62498 No, it does not

Comment: @nicomezi, in that case, I'm sorry we, in India, were taught the way I said. But in spite of this, the questioner wants to prove it finite which is wrong.